# Change domain value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three fields with NOT NULL domain. How can I change them to accept NULL data?

```
frais_inscription NUMBER(6,2) NOT NULL,
date_paiement DATE NOT NULL,
type_paiement VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you just trying to alter your table's columns to accept null?  Here is the generic syntax:

```
alter table yourtable
modify (yourfield number(6,2) null);
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2ad35/1)

Comment: +1 But I'd leave out the `number(6,2)`.  It's not necessary, and it adds the possibility of accidentally changing other properties.